# What is the equivalent of the C# "using" block in IronPython?

Tags: ironpython, idisposable

What's the equivalent of this in IronPython?  Is it just a try-finally block?

```cs
using (var something = new ClassThatImplementsIDisposable())
{
  // stuff happens here
}
```

Comment: Let's add some authority to this thread: http://lists.ironpython.com/pipermail/users-ironpython.com/2008-July/007826.html

Comment: I don't see anything in there relevant to this question.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

IronPython supports using `IDisposable` with `with` statement, so you can write something like this:

```
with ClassThatImplementsIDisposable() as something:
    pass
```

Comment: Good option for your own types, but doesn't work for framework types.

Comment: Any particular reason why it doesn't work with framework types?

Comment: Are you sure? I just tried with `StreamWriter` and it seems to work as expected.

Comment: IronPython maps IDisposable onto a set of __enter__ and __exit__ methdos for the context manager so this indeed does work w/ any type which implements IDisposable.

Answer (score 6):

IronPython (as of the 2.6 release candidates) supports the [`with`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#grammar-token-with_stmt) statement, which wraps an IDisposable object in a manner similar to using.

Comment: Just curious - why the downvotes?  As far as I know, this is true- python, as a language, doesn't include this in the language.

Comment: Actually, with is different.  It does not handle IDisposable out of the box with .NET - you would need to wrap this into your own type, and specify an __exit__ routine to do the disposal.  It is not the same as using in C#.

Comment: Downvoted because this is the same as using, and does handle IDisposable.

Comment: @Dino: That is not true in the current, stable release.  True in 2.6 RCs, though.  Updated my answer for that.

Answer (score 6):

[With statement](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement). For example:

```
with open("/temp/abc") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
```

Comment: This does not support IDisposable out of the box.  It works with python types with an __exit__ routine specified.

Answer (score 2):

There is the `with` statement: http://www.ironpythoninaction.com/magic-methods.html#context-managers-and-the-with-statement

```
with open(filename) as handle:
    data = handle.read()
    ...
```

Comment: No.  The "with" statement only works with lockable objects, to which category file objects just happens to belong.  It does *not* work with arbitrary types, say, integers.

Answer (score 0):

the using block is in fact the following under the hood:

```
try {
  (do something unmanaged here)
}
finally {
  unmanagedObject.Dispose();
}
```

Hope this helps you understand the logic behind the using statement.