# Python equivalent to C#'s using statement

Tags: python, ironpython, using

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the equivalent of the C# “using” block in IronPython?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1757296/what-is-the-equivalent-of-the-c-using-block-in-ironpython)

I'm writing some IronPython using some disposable .NET objects, and wondering whether there is a nice "pythonic" way of doing this. Currently I have a bunch of finally statements (and I suppose there should be checks for None in each of them too - or will the variable not even exist if the constructor fails?)

```
def Save(self):
    filename = "record.txt"
    data = "{0}:{1}".format(self.Level,self.Name)
    isf = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication()
    try:                
        isfs = IsolatedStorageFileStream(filename, FileMode.Create, isf)
        try:
            sw = StreamWriter(isfs)
            try:
                sw.Write(data)
            finally:
                sw.Dispose()
        finally:
            isfs.Dispose()
    finally:
        isf.Dispose()
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Python 2.6 introduced the `with` statement, which provides for automatic clean up of objects when they leave the `with` statement.  I don't know if the IronPython libraries support it, but it would be a natural fit.

Dup question with authoritative answer: [What is the equivalent of the C# "using" block in IronPython?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1757296/what-is-the-equivalent-of-the-c-using-block-in-ironpython)

Comment: thanks, that led me to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1757296/what-is-the-equivalent-of-the-c-using-block-in-ironpython, which somehow I didn't find in my previous searches

Answer (score 3):

I think you are looking for the [with statement](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#with). More info [here](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, it looks like the equivalent is the [`with`](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#with) statement. If your classes define context managers, they will be called automatically after the with block.

Answer (score 0):

Your code with some comments :

```
def Save(self):
    filename = "record.txt"
    data = "{0}:{1}".format(self.Level,self.Name)
    isf = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication()
    try:                
        isfs = IsolatedStorageFileStream(filename, FileMode.Create, isf)

        try: # These try is useless....
            sw = StreamWriter(isfs)
            try:
                sw.Write(data)
            finally:
                sw.Dispose()
        finally: # Because next finally statement (isfs.Dispose) will be always executed
            isfs.Dispose()
    finally:
        isf.Dispose()
```

For StreamWrite, you can use a with statment (if your object as **__*enter*__** and **_*exit*__** methods) then your code will looks like :

```
def Save(self):
    filename = "record.txt"
    data = "{0}:{1}".format(self.Level,self.Name)
    isf = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication()
    try:                
        isfs = IsolatedStorageFileStream(filename, FileMode.Create, isf)
        with StreamWriter(isfs) as sw:
            sw.Write(data)
    finally:
        isf.Dispose()
```

and StreamWriter in his **__*exit*__** method has

```
sw.Dispose()
```

Comment: You can also use with statement with IsolatedStorageFile class, if needed.