# close() a variable in Python

Tags: python, file

I have the following code:

```
from sys import argv

script, filename = argv

txt = open(filename)

print "Here's your file %r:" % filename
print txt.read()

print "Type the filename again:"
file_again = raw_input("> ")

txt_again = open(file_again)

print txt_again.read()
```

And in one of the exercises in my book it says "Have your script also do a `close()` on the `txt` and `txt_again` variables. It’s important to close files when you are done with them.

How can I close the variables?

Comment: `txt.close();txt_again.close()`. Btw you're not closing *variables*. You're closing the *file objects*.

Comment: Note that `with` can be used to alleviate manually management. e.g see https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4042995/python-equivalent-to-cs-using-statement

Comment: even better, use `with`, which will handle the closing for you even in case of exception.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`txt.close()` will close the file parser.  However I would suggest the use of `with` instead:

```
with open(filename) as txt:
    print "Here's your file %r:" % filename
    print txt.read()

print "Type the filename again:"
file_again = raw_input("> ")
with open(file_again) as txt_again
    print txt_again.read()
```

This ensures that the file parser is closed correctly and also make for cleaner more pythonic code.

Answer (score 4):

Do `txt.close()` and `txt_again.close()` after their respective print statements.

***EDIT:*** As others have already pointed out, using the [`with` statement](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1369526/1860929) is a much better option.

Answer (score 2):

Your book text is being unclear and imprecise. What they want you to do is call the [`file.close()` *method*](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.close) on the file objects:

```
print txt.read()
txt.close()
```

and

```
print txt_again.read()
txt_again.close()
```

A *better* idea would be to use the [`with` statement](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#with) to have Python close files for you automatically; file objects are [context managers](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#context-managers):

```
with open(filename) as txt:
    print "Here's your file %r:" % filename
    print txt.read()

print "Type the filename again:"
file_again = raw_input("> ")

with open(file_again) as txt_again:
    print txt_again.read()
```

The `with` statement tells the file object that a block begins (*entering* the context), and when the indented section ends the statement informs the file object the block has completed (*exiting* the context). A file object automatically closes itself at that point.

Answer (score 1):

Use `txt.close()`.

It's also worth noting that you are not closing a varibale, but rather a handle on the file.