# Python and SQL Bulk Insert

Tags: python, .net, sql-server, ironpython, sqlbulkcopy

I am using IronPython to create a data array and I need to insert this array to MS SQL Server.
The .Net class I'm using is SqlBulkCopy (part of System.Data.SqlClient).

I have found this StackOverflow article quite useful [SqlBulkCopy from a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3913371/sqlbulkcopy-from-a-list)

However, since I'm only starting to learn python I'm having difficulties recreating this C# example with Python code.

Here's what I have so far

```
import clr
clr.AddReference('System.Data')
from System.Data import *

import clr
clr.AddReference('System')
from System import *

sqlDbConnection = SqlClient.SqlConnection("<my-db-connection-string>")
sqlDbConnection.Open()

myDataArray = [
[Byte(7), Byte(8), Int32(1), Byte(15), Byte(12), Single(0.34324)],
[Byte(5), Byte(1), Int32(2), Byte(11), Byte(10), Single(0.77362)],
[Byte(9), Byte(2), Int32(3), Byte(12), Byte(9), Single(0.93394)]]

sqlDbConnection.Close()
```

The idea is to generate a large data array (say > 1 Million rows) and import it to my table using bulk copy method. I would really appreciate if anyone could shed a light on this and explain how I could tackle this and how I can make use of all the options that come with the bulk copy class. [SqlBulkCopy msdn reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx)

I have been looking for useful examples in Python but did not find any so far...

Much appreciated

Comment: Is this still relevant or did you manage to resolve it yourself? I saw http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14056891/f-datatable-to-sql-using-sqlbulkcopy which you posted for a similar task in F#.

Comment: I managed to work this out as well, I'm posting the answer shortly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally got my head around this one, hope this proves helpful:

```
import clr
clr.AddReference('System.Data')
from System.Data import SqlClient
from System.Data import *
from System.Data import DataTable

import clr
clr.AddReference('System')
from System import *
from System import Console
from System import Data

sqlConnectionString = "<sql-connection-string>"
sqlDbConnection = SqlClient.SqlConnection(sqlConnectionString)
sqlDbConnection.Open()

workTable = DataTable()
workTable.Columns.Add("Col1", Byte)
workTable.Columns.Add("Col2",Byte)
workTable.Columns.Add("Col3", Int32)
workTable.Columns.Add("Col4", Byte)
workTable.Columns.Add("Col5", Byte)
workTable.Columns.Add("Col6", Single)

sampleArray = [Byte(7), Byte(8), Int32(1), Byte(15), Byte(12), Single(0.34324)] 
for i in range (0, 189000) :
  workTable.Rows.Add(Array[object](sampleArray))

cmd = SqlClient.SqlCommand("truncate table dbo.MyTable", sqlDbConnection);
def bulkLoadEsgData (): 
    sbc = SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy(sqlConnectionString, SqlClient.SqlBulkCopyOptions.TableLock, BulkCopyTimeout=0, DestinationTableName="dbo.MyTable")
    sbc.WriteToServer(workTable)

# Start simulation
Console.WriteLine("Enter number of simulations (1 simulation = 189,000 data rows):"+"\n")
strN = Console.ReadLine()

n = int(strN)
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
for i in range (0, n):
    bulkLoadEsgData()

sqlDbConnection.Close()
Environment.Exit(1111)
```

Comment: Would you mind improving your code sample for future reference? You should correcly free IDisposable resources (at least for the SqlBulkCopy object, for SqlConnection and SqlCommand if possible) using `with` as seen in http://stackoverflow.com/a/1757402/468244 to avoid leaks etc. I would also avoid Environment.Exit in such a code sample because this might be a rough termination and break in a hosted scenario.