# How to avoid explicitly calling Dispose method on IDisposable object in python through pythonnet?

Tags: c#, python, mono, python.net

Recently, I developed dynamic object in C# ( a small library of sort) that I can link to my python application (excuse my nomenclature if it's not right). I have some IDisposable object that opens the file in the constructor and then closes it in `Dispose()` method. The file needs to stay open throughout the object's life.

I would expect `Dispose()` method would be call automatically after last live reference but instead I have to call it explicitly.

- Python 3.7.3
- Ubuntu 18.04.2
- pythonnet 2.4.0
- mono 5.18.1.28

```py
import clr
clr.AddReference("MyLibrary")
from MyLibrary import DynamicObject
```

and then use it further in my code:

```py
def foo():
   my_obj = DynamicObject()
   ...
   my_obj().Dispose() # have to call it here
   return
```

Moreover, the finalizer is not called either. Is there a way to make use of either finalizer or `Dispose()` method and not call them explicitly or garbage collector from CLR has no idea what is going on in my python script? How python communicates through python.net?

Thank you :- )

Comment: `I would expect Dispose() method would be call automatically after last live reference` Why did you expect that?

Comment: Huh. Yea, that was simply wrong, but Finalizer should be called, right?

Comment: The GC doesn't guarantee when or if it will call the finalizer.

Comment: @mjwills that's true, but in practice you can probably rely on it to call the finalizer soon(TM) if it's a short-lived object in Gen0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Dispose` doesn't get called automatically. It's there so that whatever uses the class can use it to dispose of unmanaged resources when required. The finalizer *will* get called automatically, but this will be whenever the garbage collector decides to do it, rather than immediately after the instance goes out of scope.

If you want to make managing your `Dispose` calls a little easier you can look at the [using statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement), which is supported by `with` [in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1757296/what-is-the-equivalent-of-the-c-sharp-using-block-in-ironpython).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I know the using statement but I'm not sure how can I use it so that the file stays open throughout object's life and I have access to it from every method. Cheers

Comment: @mjwills it does not . It has more or less equivalent ```with``` statement

Comment: Yes, I tried intuitively to do this with '''with''' statement because I thought there would be a smart mapping, however, it does not work with my environment. Now I know it works with IronPython but it's python < 3.5 so I cannot use it. Also, I would like to avoid IronPython in general. Of course, I will accept this answer if there is no way to do it in vanilla python. Thank you :)

Comment: Also, the finilizer isn't _guaranteed_ to be called at some point?

Comment: @Proko Correct. It is **not** guaranteed. _Usually_ they will, but it isn't guaranteed.